# nginx as a load balance on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-eks

I am deploying an EKS cluster and plan to use Ingress.  From my understanding when I specify `Ingress` AWS creates an Application Load Balancer.  I am having trouble figuring out how nginx will fit into this scenario as a Load Balancer since I already have a Load Balancer in AWS.

I saw an example which deploys nginx as a pod and then configures the load balancing on nginx, but why do this when you can completely do with the Application Load Balancer which comes in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons come to mind.

1. Cost - you pay per ALB.
2. Experience. If you're experienced w/ nginx ingress, why use the ALB controller?

Comment: but doesn't aws create an ALB automatically when you give ingress ? or is there a settings where it provisions an nginx pod under a specific command/setting in the yaml?

Comment: It's more nuanced. The ALB ingress is "self-contained" in the sense the ingress object is managed by AWS, it can take the user request through its endpoint and land it to the pods running your app. When you use the NGINX ingress you need a bit more work to create a fault tolerant setup. The [NGINX docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) suggests that the nginx ingress controller is deployed on multiple pods and you use an NLB as a way to reach your ingres object. So the options are really ALB ingress Vs NGINX ingress + NLB.